# XML-Attributes Character Mapping issue

Tags: xml, character-encoding, xslt-2.0

Here is a snippet from my input xml file:

```
<ARTICLE PDFID="AT-11-2013-07.pdf" DOI="AT-11-2013-07">
<ISSN>002-267</ISSN>
```

I have used character-mapping in my xslt (2.0) as below:

```
<xsl:character-map name="xyzentity">
<xsl:output-character character="-" string="&amp;hyphen;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

But the output which I get is this:

```
<ARTICLE PDFID="AT&hyphen;11&hyphen;2013&hyphen;07.pdf" DOI="AT&hyphen;11&hyphen;2013&hyphen;07">
<ISSN>002&hyphen;267</ISSN>
```

All the attribute values having `-` are getting converted to `&hyphen;` as well. I need it only in data and not in attributes. Dont know how to go about this. Help of any kind would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you replacing `-` with `&hyphen;` anyway?

Comment: The requirement is that all entities should be converted to string. Apart from attribute values.

Comment: I did not ask *what* you want to do, but *why* you want to do it. In the light of how XML works, this should be completely unnecessary.

Comment: I understand sir but the output(attributes not included) has to have string and not symbol. So I thought there must be some way to do this.

Comment: Wow, you're *really* not going to tell why, are you?

Comment: The people who require all this need it! They only know. What more can I say now! Cannot argue with them you know. Not in my hands atleast. I can only tell them that this cannot be done according to the processing standards, but `unnecessary` I am not sure.

Comment: It's like encoding all `€` characters in HTML as `&euro;`. Completely unnecessary. It's like fixing stuff that is not broken. (Put differently: While encoding it as `&euro;` might work around an incorrect `Content-Type` header, it's really not the HTML that needs fixing, but the header. That's what I suspect behind that requirement of yours. "Fixing" the XML makes matters worse, not better. Finding out what *actually* needs to be done and doing that is way smarter.)

Comment: Plus: Encoding characters in attribute values is exactly the right thing if your're going to do encoding. It makes no sense whatsoever to request *"encode in text nodes but not in attribute nodes"*.

Comment: Ok. Thank you sir. I have taken your points into consideration.

Comment: Well, I don't know since the attribte nodes in this case reference a file it's probably bad to have those encoded, even if the text nodes should be encoded, so the requirement actually still might make sense in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is asked can not be achieved using xsl:character-map because you can not selectively only apply the character mapping to some templates

I would just use something like this instead:

```
<xsl:template match="ISSN">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'-','&amp;hyphen;')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```